# How to get text from text field in tkinter and use hashlib to create a hash?

Tags: python, tkinter, hash

I have been troubled for days, I want to get text from a text field in tkinter and pass it through a hashlib function and get an output on the GUI in the second text field.
I want to create a SHA-256 one way hash.

**A link to a screenshot**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uq5K.png

```
from tkinter import *
from hashlib import sha256

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

one = Label(text="Hash Calculator", fg="Red")
one.pack()

label_1 = Label(root, text="Enter the text")
label_2 = Label(root, text="The output text is")

entry1 = Entry(root)
entry2 = Entry(root)

button_1 = Button(root, text="Submit")

one.grid(row=0, column=1)
label_1.grid(row=1)
entry1.grid(row=1, column=1)
label_2.grid(row=5,column=1)
entry2.grid(row=6, column=1)
button_1.grid(row=4, column=1)

h = sha256()
h.update(b'python1990K00L')
hash_1 = h.hexdigest()
print(hash_1)

root.mainloop()
```

I have just started learning python.

Comment: You're calculating the hash during the startup of your program.  You cannot possibly hash the user's input that way, because the user has had absolutely no chance to enter any input yet.  You need to move that code into a function specified as the `command=` option of your Button.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, and is not a way to have research, design or coding work done for you. Unfortunately `tkinter` is somewhat difficult to master because it's not well documented, in my opinion — although there are *many* tutorials about it on the web, if you bother to look for them.

That said, the following, based on the code in your question, should at least give you a basic idea of how to accomplish what you want to do.

Brief description of how it works:
It stores the user input and hash digest in two two tkinter `StrinbVar`s and attaches one to an `Entry` widget and the other to a `Label1` (using the `textvariable=` option when creating them). A function has been defined and things are set-up for it to be called whenever the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button is pressed (it's known as a "callback" function). When that happens, it gets the current text associated with `Entry`, computes the hash value for it, and then updates the variable displayed by the `Label`.

```
from tkinter import *
from hashlib import sha256


def compute_hash():
    h = sha256()
    h.update(entry.get().encode())
    hash_value.set(h.hexdigest())

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

one = Label(text="Hash Calculator", fg="Red")
one.pack()

label_1 = Label(root, text="Enter the text")
label_2 = Label(root, text="The hash value is")

text_var = StringVar(value='')
entry = Entry(root, textvariable=text_var)

digest_size = len(sha256(b'0').hexdigest())  # Compute length of hash values.
#hash_value = StringVar(value=digest_size*' ')
hash_value = StringVar()
hash_label = Label(root, textvariable=hash_value, text='')

button_1 = Button(root, text="Submit", command=compute_hash)

one.grid(row=0, column=1)
label_1.grid(row=1)
entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
label_2.grid(row=5,column=1)
hash_label.grid(row=6, column=1)
button_1.grid(row=4, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```